# Regex to store values in a variable in perl

Tags: regex, perl, multiple-columns

I have a file with data that looks a little like the example I provided. For every row starting with a name, I need to store a 1 in an arry with the size of the total number of entries if the last two columns are not null and a 0 if they are. Please help me with the regex, because I cannot seem to get it working.

```
names.txt
#+++++++++++++++
#Data for 
#++++++++++++
# name1            1 Dist94085    11    10   
# name2            2 Dist94085   100   -9    
# name3            3 Dist94086    3    
# name4            4 Dist94085    
# name5            5 Dist94086    3    6    
# name6            6 Dist94086    3    6
```

I cameup with regex /^# name\d+\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+\s+\d+/. How do I populate my results array ? I should check with last two columns. If both the columns have  a value it should store 1 else a 0.

Comment: At least show what you have tried so far...

Comment: Are there other requirements? Does the line's format have to be like what you show (starting with a '#', etc)?

Comment: yes. I'm new to perl. I built the regex, but doesnt know how to store the values in a variable and compare and store the result.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please state exactly what you are wanting to do, and how am I supposed to know where size of total entries is defined??

Comment: seemed pretty clear to me, except for not explaining what part of the data is "size of the total number of entries"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -lane 'if(/^# /){$F[4]=~m/[\-\+]*\d+/ && $F[5]=~m/[\-\+]*\d+/?push @a,1:push @a,0}END{print @a}' your_file
```

Tested:

```
> cat temp
#+++++++++++++++
#Data for 
#++++++++++++
# name1            1 Dist94085    11    10   
# name2            2 Dist94085   100   -9    
# name3            3 Dist94086    3    
# name4            4 Dist94085    
# name5            5 Dist94086    3    6    
# name6            6 Dist94086    3    6
> perl -lane 'if(/^# /){$F[4]=~m/[\-\+]*\d+/ && $F[5]=~m/[\-\+]*\d+/?push @a,1:push @a,0}END{print @a}' temp
110011
>
```

Answer (score 0):

"For every row starting with a name,"

```
perl -lane 'next unless /^# name/;
```

"I need to store ... the total number of entries"

```
push @results, scalar @F;
```

"I need to store ... 1 if the last two columns are not null and a 0 if they are."

```
push @results, ["@F[4,5]" =~ /\S/ ? 1 : 0, scalar @F]
```

Completed, with use:

```
perl -MYAML=Dump -lane 'next unless /^# name/; push @results, ["@F[4,5]" =~ /\S/ ? 1 : 0, scalar @F]; END { print Dump \@results }' names.txt
---
-
  - 1
  - 6
-
  - 1
  - 6
-
  - 1
  - 5
-
  - 0
  - 4
-
  - 1
  - 6
-
  - 1
  - 6
```

When you understand this, you can alter it to taste and to suit your actual data.

Note how what I wrote corresponds to your English description of the task -- I did not start by trying to come up with a regex that would strictly and completely match the data.